# Setting DataContext of control defined in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, datacontext, controltemplate

I'm struggling with setting DataContext of Usercontrol created using ControlTemplate.
In the code below I'd like the DriveControl's DataContext be set to it's parent's Datacontext field (pseudcode:  `DriveControl.DataContext = Parent.DataContext.DriveDataContext`). Tried setting it in ControlTemplate itself or in Style with no luck.
I'm trying to do it in XAML alone.

```
 <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Resources>                
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="DriveTemplate">
                <controls:DriveControl/>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="controls:DriveControl">

            </DataTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate  x:Key="TimeTemplate">
                <controls:TimeControl/>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate  x:Key="ApartamentTemplate">
                <controls:ApartamentControl/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
        <ContentControl.Style>                
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <!--<Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DriveTemplate}"/>-->
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentMode }" Value="Drive">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DriveTemplate}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentMode }" Value="SetTime">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TimeTemplate}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentMode }" Value="ChooseApartament">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ApartamentTemplate}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```

Comment: `<controls:DriveControl DataContext="{Binding DriveDataContext}"/>` should work, provided that the control itself does not set its own DataContext anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment I was indeed overwriting DataContext in code behind. So simply putting

```
<controls:DriveControl DataContext="{Binding DriveDataContext}"/>
```

works - unless you're a dummy and forget the code you wrote earlier (to my defence - I was inspecting source of DataContext in Live Properties, but apparently "Go To Source" only works for XAML files). Lesson learned.